# How do i add mysql_real_escape_string(): to this?

Tags: php, security

Here's the code:

```
  //check if the starting row variable was passed in the URL or not
  if (!isset($_GET['pg']) or !is_numeric($_GET['pg'])) {
 //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $startrow = 0;
//otherwise we take the value from the URL
} else {
$startrow = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pg']);
}
```

Whenever I try to add mysql_real_escape_string(); to the $_GET['pg') in the !isset, the code doesn't execute and i get no error message.

Comment: Try removing the `(int)` at the beginning of `mysql...`... It may be that

Comment: Why are you casting the result of `mysql_real_escape_string` (a string) to `int`?

Comment: Or to turn the question around, why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` here?

Comment: @olicharlesworth thanks for responding.  because $_GET variable needs to be sanitized.  Thats why i am using escape string.

Comment: @AAA: `mysql_real_escape_string` is specifically for constructing MySQL queries, not for arbitrary sanitisation.

Comment: I was under the impression that we must use mysql_real_escape_string on $_GET or $_REQUEST for a variable (e.g: domain.com/post.php?id=394Af).  If not that, then how must i sanitize the $_GET or $_REQUEST since the user can easily modify.

Comment: @AAA: No, `mysql_real_escape_string` is specifically for MySQL.  The sanitization you need to do depends on what you intend to do with the user input; there is no one-tool-fits-all sanitiser.

Comment: @olicharlesworth the $GET and $REQUEST values are used to query database.  Like to display data or to conduct searches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cast the pg value to an int.  Instead, verify that it contains an integer value, or don't execute the query. If you didn't plan on executing a query (which we can't see), then `mysql_real_escape_string()` is entirely the wrong tool since it needs a connection.

The appropriate thing to do is validate that the contents of `$_GET['pg']` is an integer, not to escape it.

Since `is_numeric()` will return TRUE for non-integer real numbers, I tend to use [`ctype_digit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) to validate positive integers. If you need the possibility of negative integers as well, you can use `ctype_digit(abs($_GET['pg']))`

```
if (!isset($_GET['pg']) or !ctype_digit($_GET['pg'])) {
   // it wasn't an integer
   // initialize to your default value
}
else {
  // $_GET['pg'] *has to be a valid int* or we wouldn't have entered the else block
  // no need to escape or further process it - it's safe to use
}
```

Comment: If i use ctype_digit will it only allow numbers? For example if someone typed in "drop table" or a link to something in the $get value, will the query break or will it simply not execute since its expecting only a numerical value!

Comment: @AAA If someone entered something that wasn't a positive integer, the code would enter the `if` case above and do whatever you defined there to handle it, whether that be to initialize a default value or redirect to another page, or whatever.

Comment: @AAA The idea is to validate that the value _is_ an integer, and if not, don't proceed to any query.

Comment: sorry if i am asking stupid questions but i am new to this.  So what i have above will ensure the query is safe even if someone is trying to break it?

Comment: additionally, i had one question.  For displaying profile pages i have a page like: profile.php?id=934af, so i am using $_GET or $_REQUEST to get the id number.  I can use myql_real_escape_string(); to the $_GET or $_REQUEST to sanitize, correct?

Comment: @AAA You can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` _if_ you have an active database connection. So after you have connected to your db successfully you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @AAA And what you have above (still recommend to replace `is_numeric()` with `ctype_digit()`) will protect the value if you then intend to pass it to a SQL query.  But if the value passes the `ctype_digit()` test as I have in my example, you don't need to escape it further - it's safe for the query.  If it passed your `is_numeric()` check, then it is also safe for SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have an integer value that is 0 or greater; that is 0 if the input is invalid:

```
$startrow = max(0, isset($_GET['pg']) ? $_GET['pg'] : 0);
```

The `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not needed for integer values. Depending on your coding style, this is possible in PHP as well:

```
$startrow = max(0, @$_GET['pg']);
```

If you're using PHP 5.4 it performs even quite well.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string requires a connection to database (second parameter), if it is not provided, last opened connection will be used - see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

might it be that at this point of your code no connection to the database was created? in that case you should see a warning (check if your php configuration allows displaing warnings)

Comment: Connection is active and it works.  I was able to test that. Thanks